# Django: date field saved to model but not retrieved

Tags: django

Django 1.9 / Python 2.7

Given this model:

```
class CoursePurchase(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    date_purchased = models.DateField(default=date.today())
```

I would expect date_purchased to store the date I enter into Django admin, and it does, according to my database browser:

[image]

However, retrieving the object in the view has today's date instead of the stored date:

[image]

(Note the date_purchased field of `__unicode__` returns today's date instead of the stored date.

Here is the code I'm using to retrieve the instance:

```
cp = CoursePurchase(course=page.course, user=request.user)
```

where `course` and `user` return the expected values.

What am I missing? This seems fairly straightforward, but I can't get past this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the current date on save, django provides special arguments to the `DateField` type:

[Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#datefield):

> `class DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, **options)`
>
> A date, represented in Python by a datetime.date instance. Has a few extra, optional arguments:
>
> **DateField.auto_now**
>
> Automatically set the field to now every time the object is saved. Useful for “last-modified” timestamps. Note that the current date is always used; it’s not just a default value that you can override.
>
> The field is only automatically updated when calling Model.save(). The field isn’t updated when making updates to other fields in other ways such as QuerySet.update(), though you can specify a custom value for the field in an update like that.
>
> **DateField.auto_now_add**
>
> Automatically set the field to now when the object is first created. Useful for creation of timestamps. Note that the current date is always used; it’s not just a default value that you can override. So even if you set a value for this field when creating the object, it will be ignored. If you want to be able to modify this field, set the following instead of auto_now_add=True:
>
> For DateField: default=date.today - from datetime.date.today()
>   For DateTimeField: default=timezone.now - from django.utils.timezone.now()
>   The default form widget for this field is a TextInput. The admin adds a JavaScript calendar, and a shortcut for “Today”. Includes an additional invalid_date error message key.
>
> The options auto_now_add, auto_now, and default are mutually exclusive. Any combination of these options will result in an error.

But that's not the cause of the issue you see. When you do this:

```
cp = CoursePurchase(course=page.course, user=request.user)
```

You are not retrieving anything from the database, but rather creating a new instance (in-memory only, not saved anywhere yet). To retrieve instances, you need to [query the database properly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/):

```
cp = CoursePurchase.objects.get(course=page.course, user=request.user)
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, I'm dumb. Thought I was missing something simple and sure enough it was.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
cp = CoursePurchase.objects.get(course=page.course, user=request.user)
```